# Select2 Dynamic Select AJAX

Tags: ajax, jquery-select2

I have the following AJAX script:

```
$.ajax({
                                type:'POST',
                                url: '/carrier/manifests/storeManifestShipments',
                                data: {
                                    proNumber: proNumber,
                                    bolNumber: bolNumber,
                                    poNumber: poNumber,
                                    SpecInst1: SpecInst1,
                                    SpecInst2: SpecInst2,
                                    SpecInst3: SpecInst3,
                                    billTo: billTo,
                                    originName: originName,
                                    originAddress1: originAddress1,
                                    originAddress2: originAddress2,
                                    originCity: originCity,
                                    originState: originState,
                                    originZip: originZip,
                                    consigneeName: consigneeName,
                                    consigneeAddress1: consigneeAddress1,
                                    consigneeAddress2: consigneeAddress2,
                                    consigneeCity: consigneeCity,
                                    consigneeState: consigneeState,
                                    consigneeZip: consigneeZip,
                                    shipmentProjectedDate: shipmentProjectedDate,
                                    shipmentWeight: shipmentWeight,
                                    shipmentPieceCount: shipmentPieceCount,
                                    createdBy: '{{Auth::user()->id}}',
                                    _token: $('input[name=_token]').val(),
                                    dataType: 'json',
                                },
                                success: function(response) {
                                    if(response !== undefined) {

                                       $('#createShipment').modal('hide');
                                       var shipmentSelect = $('.shipmentSelect');
                                       var option = new Option(response.pro_number, response.id, true, true);

                      shipmentSelect.append(option).trigger('change');

                      // manually trigger the `select2:select` event
                      shipmentSelect.trigger({
                        type: 'select2:select',
                        params: {
                          data: response
                        }
                      });
                                            console.log('success');
                                    }else{
                                            console.log('failed');
                                            console.log(response);

                                    }
                                },
                                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                  if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                                      toastr.error('Validation error - Make sure all required fields are filled!', 'Error Alert', {timeOut: 5000});
                                      console.log('Internal error: ' + jqXHR.responseText);
                                  } else if (jqXHR.status == 422) {
                                      toastr.error('Validation error - Make sure all required fields are filled!', 'Error Alert', {timeOut: 5000});
                                      console.log('Internal error: ' + jqXHR.responseText);
                                  } else {
                                      console.log('Unexpected error.');
                                  }
                                }

                            });
```

As you can see, within the success event I lay out something similar to how the example suggests it here: https://select2.org/programmatic-control/add-select-clear-items.

The problem is that it doesn't want to "select" the item from the select2 that is referenced (`.shipmentSelect`). It doesn't throw an error either, but nothing really happens. It does print the success message in the console.

The response is formatted as such:

```
id: 1
pro_number: 1234
name: person1
.....
```

So I'm curious if there is a different way of formatting it, but I believe the issue comes from the following lines:

```
  shipmentSelect.trigger({
                        type: 'select2:select',
                        params: {
                          data: response
                        }
                      });
```

I believe I need to provide maybe something else besides the general response?

Thanks